# iOS Simulator gets stuck at "Pay with Passcode" when trying Apple Pay

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-simulator, applepay

I'm trying to setup Apple Pay on my app, but I don't have an iPhone 6 with me at the moment. So I'm trying to get everything up and running with the simulator before I can go buy one, or try to get someone to lend one to me.

Anyway, I got to the point of actually showing the ApplePay view controller:

[image]

But when I tap on "Pay with Passcode" nothing happens, so I can't go any further and finish testing everything with the server.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
class PaymentVC: UIViewController,PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate {

@IBAction func onPaymentSubmit(sender: AnyObject) {
    if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks(supportedPaymentNetworks) {
        let applePayMerchantID = "merchant.com.id"

        let request = PKPaymentRequest()
        request.merchantIdentifier = applePayMerchantID
        request.supportedNetworks = supportedPaymentNetworks
        request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.Capability3DS
        request.countryCode = "US"
        request.currencyCode = "USD"
        request.paymentSummaryItems = [
            PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Custom Order", amount: NSDecimalNumber(float: total))
        ]
        let applePayController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)
        applePayController.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(applePayController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

//MARK: Apple Pay

func paymentAuthorizationViewController(controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, completion: (PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void) {

}

func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a payment status in `paymentAuthorizationViewController`. You'll see that delegate method has a completion handler that you must call to indicate whether you were able to process the payment successfully or not.

Comment: That is so weird, I would've sworn that I had a breakpoint in there and it wasn't being called. But yeah, this got it working. Thanks! In case anyone is wondering, the line to add to test a successful payment is `completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.Success)`